# Flash Games Automatation

Tags: flash, bots

I wonder if there are any methods to make a "bot" for a flash application. I used autoit and autohotkey to pick pixels from the screen and do stuff but I wonder if there is any better way.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you want to automate clicks in the flash or within the creation of in the ide, but if the last one is the csse: You can use *jsfl* to automate tasks inside the Flash IDE. You can simply create javascript-like files, save them as .jsfl and run them. These are also called *commands*.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/flash_cs5_extending.pdf

There is a very nice lib build around this, called XJSFL.
http://www.xjsfl.com/

---

**Update**:

You could use a macro recorder to record mouseclicks/keyboard keys, this one looks nice (did not test it)
http://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/

Comment: I actually want to find out if there is a better way to automate clicks and input generally in flash applications. Not at creation. Thank you for the insight though.